# Passing data to directive from component

Tags: angular, input, components, directive

I have following directive code:

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[while]' })
export class WhileDirective {

constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
            private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef)
{ }

@Input() amountOfTeams: number;
@Input() counter:number;

@Input() set while(condition: boolean) {
        some logic....

    }
}
```

My component

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {Game} from "../game";
import {PlayGameService} from "../playGame.service";


@Component({
    selector: "teams-Name",
    styleUrls:["teamsName.component.scss"],
    template: `<div  class='start-menu'>
<p  *while="" [amountOfTeams]="" [counter]=""></p>
</div>`

})

export class TeamsNameComponent {

    game: Game;
    counter:number = 0;

    constructor (public playGameService: PlayGameService) {}


    ngOnInit(){
        this.game = this.playGameService.getGame();
        console.log(this.game);
    }

}
```

I have loaded WhileDirective in declarations in my `app.module.ts`

Unfortunately I'm getting an error while compiling:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'amountOfTeams'
>   since it isn't a known property of 'p'. (" ][amountOfTeams]="" [counter]="">
>
> "): ng:///e/e.html@1:14 Can't bind to 'counter' since it isn't a known
>   property of 'p'. (" ][counter]="">

Comment: Could you post the module. I think that you didn't declare the directive in your module.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/BA05YJEIBkW8yr I did

Answer (score 0):

The error that you're receiving is because you're trying to bind to a property of the `p` element which doesn't exist.

To pass information into your structural directive, enter your logic within the double quotes of your directive.

```
<p *while="some logic"></p>
```